# Error when retrieving URL path in GAE + python + Flask

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I'm trying to retrieve the URL of my app in GAE + python + flask and get the following error when I run it locally:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Here's the snippet of code I'm utilizing to retrieve the URL path and display it.

```
import Flask, session, etc etc

... 

@app.route('/')
def main():
    if 'username' in session:
        message = self.request.path 
        return render_template('main.html', username=session['username'], message=message) 

    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

When I run the app locally on my Ubuntu machine I get the NameError copied above. I've searched in StackOverflow and some posts mention that 'self' should be invoked inside a method to exist. I'm invoking 'self' inside def main (), so I expect it to work but doesn't. It looks like I'm missing something about the scope of 'self'.

Any ideas what's wrong? Once this works I'll upload it to GAE in the cloud.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `self` in the function.  Use:

`message = request.path`